# New LED Cans installation tripping breaker

Tags: circuit-breaker, led

I'm finishing my basements.  Using [these](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-6-in-White-Integrated-LED-Recessed-Trim-2-Pack-CER6730MWH27-2/206950689?exp=inspirational&s_tnt=98739:0:0) and [these](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halo-E26-5-in-Aluminum-Recessed-Lighting-Housing-for-Remodel-Ceiling-Insulation-Contact-Air-Tite-E5RICAT/207091957).  I have 2 zones on same 15 amp circuit.  First has 9 lights.  Installed it and works fine.  2nd has 10 lights.  Installed, switched it on and after about 2 seconds the breaker trips.  I can turn on one zone or the other without tripping.  These are 11 watt LEDs so I can't be overloading it!

I started unplugging the 2nd zone from the end of the line.  When I'm down to 2 lights it works.  Pulled the 3rd can out of the ceiling and the wiring looks good.  Not sure where to go from here or what to look for.  BTW, the drywall is in.  I used the retrofit cans because I'm using hat channel and a couple layers of drywall for sound proofing and the new construction cans didn't seem to lower far enough from the joists.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Does the breaker have a "TEST" button on it?  Is the wiring for these lights near the wiring for anything else?

Comment: When you put an ammeter on it, how much current are you drawing?

Comment: are you sure the hot is hot on both?